Can we construct such a sequence with odd primes: For all $m=1,2,\ldots,N-1$, there exist $a,b$ such that $\sum_{i=a}^{m} p_i=\sum_{i=m+1}^{b} p_i$?
$$\def\e{{\bf\color{red}{=}}}
\begin{alignat}{14}
67&,&43&,&11&,&13&,&19&,&7&,&5&,&31&,&3&,&2&,&41&,&29&,&17&,&89&\\
67&\e&43&+&11&+&13\\
&&43&\e&11&+&13&+&19\\
67&+&43&+&11&\e&13&+&19&+&7&+&5&+&31&+&3&+&2&+&41\\
&&43&+&11&+&13&\e&19&+&7&+&5&+&31&+&3&+&2\\
&&&&11&+&13&+&19&\e&7&+&5&+&31\\
&&&&&&13&+&19&+&7&\e&5&+&31&+&3\\
&&&&&&&&19&+&7&+&5&\e&31\\
&&&&&&13&+&19&+&7&+&5&+&31&\e&3&+&2&+&41&+&29\\
&&&&11&+&13&+&19&+&7&+&5&+&31&+&3&\e&2&+&41&+&29&+&17\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&5&+&31&+&3&+&2&\e&41\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3&+&2&+&41&\e&29&+&17\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&31&+&3&+&2&+&41&+&29&\e&17&+&89\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&2&+&41&+&29&+&17&\e&89
\end{alignat}$$
The example shown above is for the sequence $67,43,11,13,19,7,5,31,3,2,41,29,17,89$ consisting of $14$ primes. My question is whether we can construct such a sequence with primes other than $2$.
More precisely, it can be expressed as follows:
Is there a sequence $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_N$ consisting of $N$ distinct odd primes that satisfies the following condition:
For all $m=1,2,\ldots,N-1$, there exist $a,b$ such that $\sum_{i=a}^{m} p_i = \sum_{i=m+1}^{b} p_i$?
I tried the following:
In the case of primes including $2$, I found a sequence shown at the top by searching on a computer. This is an example where the largest prime in the sequence is the smallest, which is $89$. If we use primes up to $89$, there are only two examples: the sequence shown at the top and the reverse sequence of this sequence.
For a small number of terms, it is possible to manually try all cases by case analysis, but it is challenging. I was only able to try up to 6 terms manually.
Additionally, I searched for all possible combinations of odd primes up to $109$ using depth-first search on a computer and found no such sequence.

I am not sure this is very clear. Specifically, you don't seem to include all possibilities of 'putting an equal sign'. For instance, the sequence you show does not contain an equation for $67+43$.

Is $2$ an odd prime as you restrict in your headline? (In the sense of 'odd' = uneven)

I am considering sequences that have at least one equation between each pair of terms, that the left and right sides of the equation are equal by extending the plus signs to some extent on both sides. In this example, since $43=11+13+19$, $67+43=\ldots$ is not necessary.

As shown in my example, we can construct such a sequence with primes including $2$. So, I am considering whether we can construct such a sequence with primes excluding $2$.

The sequence $67, 43,11,13,19$ satisfies your requirements, doesn't it?

This is very confusing. You established many equations at different positions. What exactly is the system of equations you are after ?

@jjagmath No, it does not. $67=43+11+13$, $43=11+13+19$, but we cannot construct equations like "$\ldots11=13\ldots$" or "$\ldots13=19$".

I am considering a sequence that can construct $N-1$ equations if the number of terms is $N$. The position of the equal sign is important, and the number of plus signs is not restricted. The example I showed is the case of $N=14$. In the example I showed, $14$ primes are used, and $13$ equations are constructed. The $\bf\color{red}{=}$ signs are inserted between each pair of terms in order. I apologize for causing confusion to many people.

And it didn't occur to you too explain all that in the original question? Even after some comments about the lack of clarity of your question? You should edit your question and explain exactly what are you looking for.

@jjagmath Thank you for the advice. I thought one example would explain everything, but I realized it was not enough. I have edited the question. I hope it is now clearer.

Do you mean to restrict to sequences of distinct odd primes? And is your question whether one can construct arbitrary long sequences with this property?

@GregMartin Yes, I am looking for finite sequences consisting of odd primes without duplication (otherwise, trivial sequences such as $3, 3, 3$ would fit the criteria). As for the length, there are no specific restrictions. Literally, I want to know whether finite sequences with this property can exist. I recently edited my question, but did my wording cause further confusion? If you have any suggestions for improvement, they are welcome.
